# Sass for a project created by Sidekick

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I've followed the instructions on the Nativescript site to a tee.

First I create a new project using sidekick using blank angular for the template. Then I install the sass plugin:

`tns install sass`

I create the files:

`app.ios.scss
app.android.scss
_app-common.scss`

next to the app.compoenent.ts file and use

`@import "app-common"`

In order to get the sass compiler to run, I have to remove the app.css file next to main.ts in the root src directory. I can see the files compile, but when I run the app, it does not pick up my styles. It appears I need to add some kind of config to recognize the app.ios.css file in the app folder. Does anyone know how I do this? The sidekick app sets up the src and the app folders for me.

[image: my directory structure]

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean by "next to the app.compoenent.ts file and use"? You don't have to import anything on `app.component.ts`. `app.*.scss` file will be picked up by default.

Comment: I don't import, I just place it in the same directory:

Comment: It must be at root level of your project where you have your `main.ts` usually.